# Comparison of import vs <script> tag

Tags: javascript

Are there any benefits (e.g. performance, speed etc) between `import` and `<script>` tag for shared code inclusion in the following basic (non-library) examples?
What are the pros/cons?

**via `<script>` tag**

```js
// common.js
class SomeClass {
 // code 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Popup</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <!-- HTML -->

  <script src="common.js"></script>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**via `import`**

```js
// common.js
export class SomeClass {
 // code 
} 


// popup.js
import {SomeClass} from './common.js'
```

Comment: @Adriani6 I had read that one before posting. I am interested in performance & speed comparison which the other topic does not mention. It also said `<script>` is synchronous but does that mean `import` isnt?!!

Comment: Your first example is missing the contents of the *popup.js* file and the second example is missing the html document. We cannot really compare them. In any case, you should choose modules for all the reasons other than speed alone.

Comment: @Bergi What are other reasons for choosing modules over `<script>`? For example, I have a file (400+ lines) with 3  `class` (not-library) that is shared. Which method is best and why?

Comment: @erosman Scoping and explicit dependency declaration. It doesn't need a library to find that useful.

Comment: @erosman my bad!

Comment: One benefit is that the modules declare what they depend on (`import`). This information is used by the browser to generate a dependency graph, which is then used to determine the right order of executing modules. This versus having to arrange the `<script>` elements in the right order. Also, a lot of `<script>` tags can get unwieldy. Scripts depend on implicitly present globals which may not be there. Etc.

Comment: Thank you @Joseph That makes sense. In an add-on, browser caches files on startup. I read that `import` actually fetches the file at the time of calling. Although fetch is also cached, it will still generate a process to check for changes while the file cache is static. I was wondering if that is the case, the performance of static files via `<script>` could be better!!?