# ES Module loading Performance: script tag with defer vs import

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

*Note: Previously asked the question about `script` tag but without `defer`, in [Comparison of import vs `<script>` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63511134/comparison-of-import-vs-script-tag). This question is also aimed at browser extension environment.*

When loading multiple JS modules, which method preforms better?

Does `<script defer>` fetch files concurrently or sequentially?

**optuions.html**

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="mod1.js" defer></script>
    <script src="mod2.js" defer></script>
    <script src="mod3.js" defer></script>
    ...
  </head>
...
```

Does `import` fetch files concurrently or sequentially?

**options.js**

```js
import {Mod1} from './mod1.js';
import {Mod2} from './mod2.js';
import {Mod3} from './mod3.js';
...
```

Comment: Loading from network can be concurrent, running is sequential because a single JS context (such as the page's JS context) is single-threaded by design. There should be no difference in performance.

Comment: There should be no noticeable difference, but you should use a profiler to compare it, because importing uses a slightly more complicated logic.